# threejs clipping 'sphere' possible?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm looking to find out if its possible to create a sphere that handles clipping in threejs. At the moment I'm building a series of clipping planes to handle all directions as shown in the image, but this seems rather wasteful. If its just affecting a material property would it not be possible for a sphere or rect geo to do the same thing.

[image]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Clipping does not affect material. Clipping affects which parts of the geometry are rendered. This is done by intersecting the particular geometry with the clipping primitive. WebGL supports user-defined clipping planes (as in your example) but not spheres. However, you could write a fragment shader that inspects the fragment's x,y,z position and discards the fragment if it lies outside a specified sphere.

Comment: WebGL does not support clipping planes. Any clipping planes you want are entirely up to you to implement. Maybe you meant to say three.js supports clipping planes? (I don't know if three.js does or not)

Comment: alright then, thanks for the info. Pity this isn't native to threejs